# How to use HTML tags in form error messages

Tags: 8

I'm using **\Drupal\Core\Form\FormState::setError()** in a form validation hook to display a message if the validation fails. I want to include some HTML on it, but the second parameter of **setError()**, the error message, is escaped. As a result, the HTML code is visible in the message box. How can I avoid this and have HTML in the box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All errors added to the form state will be finally handled by [`drupal_set_message`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.2.x).
That means that you can either use strings, or any class that implements the [`MarkupInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21MarkupInterface.php/interface/MarkupInterface/8.2.x).
Looking at that [list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21MarkupInterface.php/interface/implements/MarkupInterface/8.2.x) I would say that what you are looking for is [`FormattableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.2.x) or even better [`TranslatableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3A__construct/8.2.x).

An example would then be:

```
$your_error = new TranslatableMarkup('<b>@message!</b>', array('@message' => 'A bold error'));
$form_state->setError($element, $your_error);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Great answer. `t()` is the same code, still the most used function in Drupal: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!StringTranslation!StringTranslationTrait.php/function/StringTranslationTrait%3A%3At/8.2.x

Comment: Works great. I was passing a simple string instead of an instance of `TranslatableMarkup`. Objects implementing this class, according to the interface [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21MarkupInterface.php/interface/MarkupInterface/8.2.x), "will not be automatically XSS filtered by the render system or automatically escaped by the theme engine", which is what I needed. In this particular case all code is internal, coming from entityQuery, so security is not affected by avoiding those filters.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer does not allow HTML inside the `@message`, here is what worked for me.

```
  $message = '<b>A bold error</b>';
  $rendered_message = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($message);
  $error_message = new TranslatableMarkup ('@message', array('@message' => $rendered_message));
  $form_state->setErrorByName('field_name', $error_message);
```

**Important:** For security reasons, make sure that `$message` value is authored by an admin only; otherwise, you cannot use this answer!

**Note:** You have to declare the new dependency at top of your class.php file, or you will receive an error and WSOD in browser:

```
use \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;
```